# how can I the get data of the posting users in Instagram from Facebook GraphAPI?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, data-mining

Facebook in the GraphApi send post details without user information. but I need to users data for my analytics production.
in GraphApi docs write you cant get posting users media object.[GraphApi Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfkS3.png)

I tried with PrivateAPI package for get data and هt has been successful. but I need a legal way